# How to run several operations back to back in a lambda in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm teaching myself Haskell, and I am having difficulty understanding how I might pipeline a number of operations in the body of a lambda function without using a do block. Take the following for example:

```
par = (\c->
    c + 1
    c + 2
  )
```

In Ruby and other imperative languages, I am used to being able to run serveral expressions in a lambda block by adding a linebreak between them. In Haskell, I looked for a similar construct and found that Haskell doesn't respect linebreaks in pure expressions.

So, syntactically, if I wanted to run the second line after the first without using a do block, what could I do?

Comment: If you are intending to use these as imperative commands, either use a `do` block or use the `>>` and `>>=` operators (which a `do` block is short for -- see any monad tutorial).  If, on the other hand, these are not monadic actions, then it is not meaningful to do something "after" something else without combining their results in some way.

Comment: It would be helpful if we knew more about what you are trying to do here....  What are `Concurrent`, `unwrap`, and `fork` (are these from `Control.Concurrent`?)  What is the function trying to do....  Haskell always takes values after an expression as function parameters, even if the expression is in a paren, so I see why the error comes up, but I don't know how to tell you to fix it.

Comment: @jamshidh Thanks for the response. The example comes from Erik Meijer's edx course, but my question is about the syntax. Isn't the line break here enough for the compiler to see that the second line is a new expression?

Comment: @AndrewC I will try to write up the definitions, but my question is only about the syntax. In other languages a new line is interpreted as a new expression, but Haskell doesn't seem to do that in a lambda –– am I wrong to think that?

Comment: Modified my question to make it clear it's about the syntax.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. What is `par 3` supposed to evaluate to?

Comment: It's clearer now what you're asking. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to return something like a 2-tuple, like `(6,7)`, because otherwise, the previous computations are just wasted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless it's side-effectful code, having multiple independent expressions with no side effects makes no sense in Haskell (nor any other languages for that matter). You can use `let` to store the value of an expression in a name and then use it in the subsequent expression (the returm value of the lambda), or a `do`-block, but anything else is meaningless in Haskell and thus not a valid program.

In other words: it makes little sense to ask this question solely about syntax as Haskell's syntax is all about its semantics.